# SQLAlchemyの検索条件組み立て

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

12月からPythonを学び始めました。FlaskとSQLAlchemyを使ってアプリを作ろうとしています。

困ったのが、検索条件の組み立てです。ベタにやるとこんな感じになると思います。名前と苗字を検索条件に入れてユーザーを探すイメージです。

```
def search():
  firstname =''
  lastname = ''
  rs = session.Query(User)
  if firstname:
     rs = rs.filter(User.firstname==firstname)
  if lastname:
     rs = rs.filter(User.lastname==lastname)
```

これしか方法が無いなら諦めるのですが、例えば検索条件に入れた変数(この場合はfirstname,lastname)がNoneとか空文字だったらfilterを通しても無視されるような感じに出来たら良いなぁ...と。

ユーザーから与えられる複数のリクエストパラメータに対して、よりスマートに検索条件を組み立てる方法があればご教示頂けると幸いです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

細かい実行確認はしてないですが、多分

```
def search():
  firstname =''
  lastname = ''
  rs = session.Query(User)
  rs = rs.filter((User.firstname==firstname) | (not firstname))
  rs = rs.filter((User.lastname==lastname) | (not lastname))
```

で、いけるんじゃないでしょうか（ただ、フィルタにはなってしまいますが）。

`&` `|`  は SQLAlchemyがビット演算子をオーバーロードしているものなので、 and, or ではありません。

`&` `|` を使う代わりに `or_`, `and_` というのもあったと思います。

```
  rs.filter(or_(User.firstname==firstname, not firstname))
```

そうじゃなくて、イコールの比較がそもそもいらないなら
（ 検索条件値が SQLでいうところの`firstname = '' or firstname is null`の時、  DBの値に依らず trueにしたいなら）

```
  rs.filter(not firstname).filter(not lastname)
```

で、いいと思います。

Answer (score 2):

やはりベタですが、以下の様にも書けるかと思います。

```
rs.filter(and_(and_(User.firstname != '',
                    User.firstname != None,
                    User.firstname == firstname),
               and_(User.lastname  != '',
                    User.lastname  != None,
                    User.lastname  == lastname))
```

`firstname` や `lastname` 変数が空文字列や None であってもマッチするレコードはないはずです。まぁ、DB テーブルの当該カラムに NOT NULL 制約を設定してしまえば良いのかも知れませんが、空文字列と NULL を別個に扱う DB では不十分かもしれません。

ところで、上記のフィルタがどの様な WHERE 句(SQL)になるのかを確認したい場合には、そのまま print します。

```
print and_(and_(User.firstname != '',
                User.firstname != None,
                User.firstname == firstname),
           and_(User.lastname  != '',
                User.lastname  != None,
                User.lastname  == lastname))
=>
"User".firstname != :firstname_1 AND "User".firstname IS NOT NULL AND
"User".firstname = :firstname_2 AND "User".lastname != :lastname_1 AND
"User".lastname IS NOT NULL AND "User".lastname = :lastname_2
```

変数などはキーワード変数に置き換えられてしまいますが、確認には十分かと思います。

Answer (score 2):

質問に書かれているようにPython側のif文で filter 追加を分岐させるのが一般的によいパフォーマンスを得られると思います。
filterの中でどうにかしようとすると生成されるSQLが複雑になり index が利用されなくなる可能性が高くなります。

Answer (score 1):

いろいろな条件から、 `filter()` に指定する引数を動的に生成するという話しなら、こんな感じでも書けます。

```
def query(**kwargs):
    exprs = [(getattr(User, name) == value) 
        for name, value in kwargs.items() if value is not None]

    return session.query(User).filter(*exprs).all()
```

呼び出すときは、必要なフィールド名と値を指定して

```
print(list(query(firstname='john', lastname='smith')))
```

な感じで。

演算子の指定順はバラバラになりますので、検索のパフォーマンスに影響したりするかもしれませんが...

Comment: これはexprsが最終的に空リストになっても正常に動作するでしょうか？

Comment: SQLAlchemyの動作についてお知りになりたければ、あたらしい質問を起こされたほうが適切だと思います。